# 6n137 does not work

Tags: opto-isolator

[image]
Hi,

I've tried every configuration on keys (except shortcutting of course). No matter what I do there is:

V1 = 3,08 V (unless k1 is open)

V2 = 0,1÷0,2 V (no matter what I do)

Did I kill it? Or I did sth wrong?

Comment: Well, \$V_1\$ measured across the \$330\:\Omega\$ resistor doesn't look wrong to me. That part is probably working fine. Try adding a \$10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ pullup resistor from the output to your \$+5\:\textrm{V}\$ rail. See if that helps. Leave \$V_E\$ unconnected.

Comment: Jonk is right. The datasheet says "*The 6N137, VO2601, and VO2611 are single channel
10 MBd optocouplers utilizing a high efficient input LED
coupled with an integrated optical photodiode IC detector.
**The detector has an open drain NMOS-transistor output**,
providing less leakage compared to an open collector
Schottky clamped transistor output.*" I *think* the enable input should be pulled high. See [datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137vo2.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

What's missing is an output pull-up. If you look carefully at all the test-setups in the [6N137 datasheet](http://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137vo2.pdf) you will see that they all have a pull-up named R<sub>L</sub> connected from the output to VCC.

There is a table called *Recommended Operating Conditions* which recommends that R<sub>L</sub> should be between 330 and 4000 Ohm for a supply voltage of 4.5 to 5.5 volts. I imagine that you can make this value even higher, but then they can not guarantee the fastest switching speed. It is a trade-off between power and speed.

There is sadly not a simple "example usage" connection in the datasheet, but the closest is probably *Fig. 4 - Single Channel Test Circuit for Common Mode Transient Immunity*:

[image]

If you just delete the pulse generator, it shows a reasonable example circuit.

Answer (score 2):

The 6N137 has an "Open Drain" output - the output stage can only pull the output to ground.  The external circuit must pull the output up towards the positive supply to get a High output.

Try a 5K - 10K resistor from the output pin to the positive supply (and you can leave the EN pin unconnected).